# How to autoincrement primary key in mysql based on hibernate mapping?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I want hibernate to autogenerate the following sql for the id column:

`create table test (id bigint not null auto_increment)`

The following 2 mappings would both trigger that sql. Where is the exact difference? Why should I favor one over the other?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
private Long id;
```

I'm using mysql, spring-boot-2 and hibernate-5.

**Sidenote to the comments**: I don't want to be explained the difference between TABLE, IDENTITY or SEQUENCE. I'm also not asking which of them is better regarding performance. Instead I'm simply asking where the difference between `IDENTITY` and `AUTO with native` is, as both leads to the same `sql` creation statement...